# Get the shared text from other apps in React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, intentfilter, share-extension

I want to get the shared text from other apps, I refer to [this article](https://medium.com/swlh/sharing-image-to-android-app-using-intent-filter-to-react-native-d112308328d5), use intent-filter but it is not so smooth, I found that I need to get the intent from onCreate or onNewIntent to process, but the problem is that createReactActivityDelegate and getLaunchOptions always take precedence Execution, I can't get the intent and then pass it to React Native. Am I missing something? Or is there another way to replace the intent-filter, and I plan to use the share extension for iOS. Is this suitable for react native? Thanks in advance.

Q:

1. createReactActivityDelegate and getLaunchOptions always execute before onCreate and onNewIntent, so I can not send the intent to React Native.
2. I plan to use the share extension for iOS. Is this suitable for react native?
3. Is there another way to replace the intent-filter and share extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update my solution.

1. I send the event to JavaScript when I got the shared text, but be aware of the life cycle of NativeModules.
2. It is my first time using share extension and it working fine.
3. I didn't specifically look for other alternatives.

I hope this information can help you who has the same question.